# Differential equation $\frac{y}{y+x}dx = dy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the problem $(x+y)u_x + yu_y = 0$ with the condition $u(x,x) = x$.
I assume that $u_xdx + u_ydy = 0$

Now I am wondering, how do we solve $\frac{y}{y+x}dx = dy$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:$\dfrac{dx}{dy} = \dfrac{y+x}{y} = 1 + \dfrac{x}{y} \Rightarrow x' -\dfrac{1}{y}x = 1$. View this as a first order ODE in $x =f(y)$. Can you continue?

Second method using @mickep's answer:

$z = \dfrac{y}{x} \to y = zx \to y'= (zx)' = xz' + z = \dfrac{y}{y+x} = \dfrac{z}{z+1}$. Can you take it from here as well?

Comment: First I solve homogenous part $x' -\dfrac{1}{y}x = 0$ And I get $x = Cy$, then I use the variation of constant to solve the particular part, which means $x = yC(y) and x' = yC'(y) + C$ and finally, $C' = 1/y$, so $x = Cy + ylny$

Comment: Thanks for advice @Back2Basic. How would I solve the equation by method proposed by @mickep?

Comment: Please see my edit which has the part you need.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=y/x$ and you will find (in the end, after switching back) that $x=Cy+y\ln y$. (This also implies it is not possible to express $y$ in terms of $x$ using elementary functions, only.)

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
The following method is discussed in
[V. A. Dorodnit︠s︡yn Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420083090).

---

If you 'scale' the variables $\ds{x}$ and $\ds{y}$, $\ds{\pars{~x = \alpha\tilde{x}\,,\ y=\beta\tilde{y}~}}$
the equation $\ds{y' = {y \over y + x}}$ becomes:
$$
\totald{\tilde{y}}{\tilde{x}}={y \over \pars{\beta/\alpha}\tilde{y} + \tilde{x}}
$$
So, the equation is unchanged, in form, whenever $\ds{\alpha = \beta}$. Namely,
$$
{x \over \tilde{x}}={y \over \tilde{y}}\quad\imp\quad
{y \over x}={\tilde{y} \over \tilde{x}}
$$
It means that a scaling which do not modify $\ds{y/x}$ leads to an equation which preserves its form. In addition, it means that $\ds{y/x}$ should be used as a new variable $\ds{{y \over x} = u}$. That was the way other answers followed:
$$
y=ux\quad\imp\quad u'x + u={ux \over ux + x}={u \over u + 1}\quad\imp\quad
\pars{{1 \over u} + {1 \over u^{2}}}u' = -1.
$$
which obviously leads to the transcendent equation
$$
\ln\pars{\frac{y}{x}} - {x \over y}=-x + \mbox{a constant}.
$$